# fading text using div tag

Tags: html, fade, fadein, fadeout

fading text using div tag

any help....???

Comment: Help with what, specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is not so clear, I assume you want javascript to do this. If you can use jQuery then, you can use [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) to achieve this effect.

See a **[working demo](http://jsbin.com/axisu)**.